# Insert & Delete from SQL best practice

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a database with 2 tables:  CurrentTickets & ClosedTickets.  When a user creates a ticket via web application, a new row is created.  When the user closes a ticket, the row from currenttickets is inserted into ClosedTickets and then deleted from CurrentTickets.  If a user reopens a ticket, the same thing happens, only in reverse.

The catch is that one of the columns being copied back to CurrentTickets is the PK column (TicketID)that idendity is set to ON.

I know I can set the IDENTITY_INSERT to ON but as I understand it, this is generally frowned upon.  I'm assuming that my database is a bit poorly designed.  Is there a way for me to accomplish what I need without using IDENTITY_INSERT?  How would I keep the TicketID column autoincremented without making it an identity column?  I figure I could add another column RowID and make that the PK but I still want the TicketID column to autoincrement if possible but still not be considered an Idendity column.

Comment: What is your version of SQL server?

Comment: Why don't you just have one table and have a status that includes closed or current? This copying and deleting rows all over the place sounds like an unnecessary nightmare.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple answer is DO NOT make an Identity column if you want your influence on the next Id generated in that column.

Also I think you have a really poor schema, Rather than having two tables just add another column in your `CurrentTickets` table, something like `Open BIT` and set its value to `1` by default and change the value to `0` when client closes the Ticket.

And you can Turn it On/Off as many time as client changes his mind, with having to go through all the trouble of Insert Identity and managing a whole separate table.

### Update

Since now you have mentioned its SQL Server 2014, you have access to something called `Sequence Object`.

You define the object once and then every time you want a sequential number from it you just select next value from it, it is kind of hybrid of an Identity Column and having a simple INT column.

Comment: Thanks for the thoughts Tanner and M.Ali.  I had thought of that but I was concerned that over time the size of the table would get too large.  I'll have about 75 users Creating and closing tickets.  They will only be able to see the tickets that they themselves create.  I was assuming (probably incorrectly) that having the server query a table with thousands of rows (eventually) for 2 parameters (closed,and by creator) would be more taxing and take longer than just querying by creator.

Comment: If you ever get to a stage where you think this Table alone is not able to handle the amount of data it holds, consider adding partitions. but do you reckon you will be hitting a 100 million rows in a year ? if not then dont worry about the size of table. just add enough indexes on the table so you queries arent starving of enough resources.

Comment: Just make them two fields `Creator` and `Open/Closed` small data types like you can make Open/closed a BIT field, Creator use INT datatype like CreatorID, The smaller the data type is faster the queries will be.

Comment: Okay, one last quick part M.Ali.  The closed table has a couple extra columns:  ClosedBy, ClosedDate.  I'm assuming I can leave those in the main Tickets as well without affecting much?  Only 20 or so will be open at once and therefore have null values in the table until it is closed.  I won't be anywhere close to a 100 million rows a year.

Comment: Right instead of having `ClosedBy` and `ClosedDate`, why dont you have columns like `UpdatedBy` and `LastUpdated`? will give you more information with the same columns, anytime any change is made to a row both columns will be updated, person who made the change and when the change was made? do you reckon its a better option?

Comment: I was planning to use an int for CreatorID that links back to another table with creator info.  The Join Statment pulling the creator info to link with the ticket isn't considered to inefficient.  Last one I swear.  I know this is getting off topic of the original post.

Comment: You are spot on there, this is how it should be :)

Answer (score 2):

This just seems like bad design with 2 tables. Why not just have a single tickets table that stores all tickets. Then add a column called `IsClosed`, which is false by default. Once a ticket is closed you simply update the value to true and you don't have to do any copying to and from other tables.

All of your code around this part of your application will be much simpler and easier to maintain with a single table for tickets.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this in latest versions of SQL Server use `OUTPUT` clause ([definition on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms177564.aspx)).

**OUTPUT clause** used with a table variable:

```
declare @MyTableVar (...)

DELETE FROM dbo.CurrentTickets
OUTPUT DELETED.* INTO @MyTableVar
WHERE <...>;

INSERT INTO ClosedTicket
Select * from @MyTableVar
```

Second table should have `ID` column, but without `IDENTITY` property. It is enforced by the other table.